# Segment depth image with low contrast

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation, edge-detection

I am trying to segment the hand from this *depth* image:

[image]

I tried watershed, region growing, grabcut, but all of them failed mainly because there is not a clear edge. I tried to sharp the image as well, but it didn't give me good results either.

Comment: is this your original resolution and color depth? if not, please provide original sample image so a method can be tested before it will be proposed.

Comment: @Micka I updated to the original color depth (and this is the original resolution of my DS325 camera). The only thing is that the input was converted from float (varying from -1 to 0.6) to uchar to be saved as jpg. If you think is better to send in float format, I can link a txt file.

Comment: link the txt file in addition please =)

Comment: @Micka Its [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5200032/output.txt)  (the size is 320x240). And thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: with some prior knowledge it might be possible (still hard) to segment most of the hand, but I have no idea at all how to get the thumb...

Comment: Yes, for now I was using color information, but I don't like it since any table with skin color give me bad results. And since I can see the borders with my eyes, there must be a way to solve this...

Comment: probably your brain enhances the thumb outlines because your brain already detected the rest of the hand ;)
It is quite challenging to use the humand brain as a reference for segmentation algorithms!

Answer (score 4):

This might not be the answer you were hoping for, but it might help you step forward a bit. Since I only provide algorithmic hints I will use Matlab rather than opencv.

Since this is not an ordinary intensity image, but rather depth image, you should use the implied *geometry* of the scene. The key assumption that can help you here is that the hand is resting on a **surface**. If you can estimate the surface equation, you can detect the hand much easier.

```
[y x] = ndgrid( linspace(-1,1,size(img,1)), linspace(-1,1,size(img,2)) );
X = [reshape(x(101:140,141:180),[],1), reshape(y(101:140,141:180),[],1), ones(1600,1)];
srf=(X\reshape(img(101:140,141:180),[],1)); %// solving least-squares for the 40x40 central patch

 aimg = img - x*srf(1) - y*srf(2) - srf(3); %// subtracting the recovered surface
```

Using median filter to "clean" it a bit, and applying a simple thereshold

```
 medfilt2(aimg,[3 3]) < -1.5
```

Yields

[image]

Not exactly what you were hoping for, but I think it's a step forward ;)

---

PS,
You might find the work of [*Alpert, Galun, Nadler and Basri* **Detecting faint curved edges in noisy images** (ECCV2010)](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~meirav/Curves_Alpert_Galun_Nadler_Basri.pdf) relevant to your problem.

Comment: thank you for the answer! Actually I had this same idea. With RANSAC I extracted the plane very well, but I still miss the fingertips (which is what I'm looking for). And thanks for pointing out the paper, I'll take a look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Please check my code implementation.

```
void applyClahe(const cv::Mat& src, cv::Mat& dst)
{
    cv::Mat lab;
    cv::cvtColor(src, lab, cv::COLOR_BGR2Lab);

    vector<cv::Mat> labChannels;
    cv::split(lab, labChannels);

    auto clahe = cv::createCLAHE();
    cv::Mat cl; clahe->apply(labChannels[0], cl);
    cl.copyTo(labChannels[0]);

    cv::merge(labChannels, dst);
    cv::cvtColor(dst, dst, cv::COLOR_Lab2BGR);
}
```

This function will give you the following result and good starting point.
[image: CLAHE Result]